# Чем скачать все страницы чужого сайта (нужно логинится на сайте)?

Tags: поиск-программ

Порекомендуйте решение для скачивания тех страниц сайта какие посещаешь. Что-то типа истории браузера, только с сохранением страниц. Вручную можно, но результат такой себе.

Лет 5-10 назад было рабочее решение: для Firefox дополнение "ScrapBook X", а для него была еще надстройка "ScrapBook X AutoSave". Их уже нету, а старые версии дополнений в старую версию браузера не устанавливаются.

Там не только автоматически сохранялись страницы во время серфинга, но и менялись ссылки. Если страница скачена, то на остальных скаченных страницах все ссылки на нее вели на скаченную версию, а не на сайт. Круто было.
Сейчас есть что-то подобное?

ПС: найденный мною отдельный софт для скачивания сайта не очень подходит, на сайте нужно будет залогиниться, чтобы посмотреть содержимое.

Comment: Увы нет аналога ScrapBook X AutoSave

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая программка называться httrack

- https://www.httrack.com/

Очень гибкая в настройках, фактический копирует весь сайт целиком.

Comment: Я ее пробовал, не нашел способа залогиниться

Comment: Посмотри документацию на `before start` и `cookie jar`

Comment: Логин и пароль нашел, но все равно ничего не сохраняет. Выдает ошибку https://prnt.sc/jXuDAAE-POzd

Comment: Посмотри `hts-log.txt` и `cookies.txt` после запуска. И сравни с куками браузера. Скорее всего ты неправильно прошел авторизацию. Поэтому и не получилось. По логам ты узнаешь что пошло не так. В чём прикол, что сам по себе httrack - консольная утилита. И GUI не всегда корректно отображает что именно произошло с консольным приложением.

Comment: На самом деле, httrack очень мощная консольная утилита, если научиться ей правильно пользоваться, то качать сайты в оффлайн проще простого.

Answer (score -1):

"логиниться" вам ни чего не даст.
Движок скачать можно лишь с FTP.
Вы скачаете лишь результат работы движка.

Comment: Мне не движок нужен, а именно результат

Comment: Раньше программы были такие. Поищите. Возможно и сейчас они есть.
Я допустим шаблоны качаю через банальный Ctrl+S. А сам сайт весь, качать не вижу практического смысла. Вы вероятно новичок в разработке? В чём суть? Поясните, мне как разработчику. Не понимая смысла трудно давать верный ответ.

Comment: Это не для разработки, а для сохранения информации.

Comment: Та по сути уже поздно. Доступ к сайту уже закрыт, подписка кончилась. Сохранил через Ctrl+S - за неделю, каждый день по несколько часов. Спасибо всем кто откликнулся.